# Replace the second and third with . if it is 0

Tags: awk

I have data with three fields. Fields 2 and 3 can be zero and I want to change to "."  if it is zero.

Example data:

```
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 1
5 1 0
```

Here is what I tried:

```
awk '{
     if($2=="0" && $3=="0"){
     `$3=".";`
     `$2=".";`
       }
       else if($3=="0"){
        $3="."
        } 
      else if($2=="0"){
       $2="." }
       else {
        $2=$2;
        $3=$3;
        }

     print $0
}' file.txt>changedfile.txt
```

It changed only the second field but not the third field.
Thanks a lot, I want to do it with Awk control structure

Comment: first field won't be 0 in any cases? also all digits are in a single length digit? if so then I will undelete my given answer `awk '{ gsub("0" , ".") }1'` that I believe it's the best one suit your question. please [edit] your question and clarify.

Answer (score 4):

With more Generic approach here, please try following solution. You need to simply pass field numbers where you want to perform check and replace it will dot in case its zero pass its field number to function named `fillValues` right now I have passed `fillValues(2,3)` since you want to check 2nd and 3rd fields only, this can handle n number of fields.

```
awk '
function fillValues(fields){
  num=split(fields,arr,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    $arr[i]=$arr[i]==0?".":$arr[i]
  }
}
{
  fillValues("2,3")
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
function fillValues(fields){         ##Starting function named fillValues with passing fields variable in it.
  num=split(fields,arr,",")          ##Splitting fields values into arr with delimiter of , here.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){               ##Starting a for loop till value of num here.
    $arr[i]=$arr[i]==0?".":$arr[i]   ##Checking if current field is 0 then assign dot or keep it as it is.
  }
}
{
  fillValues("2,3")                  ##Calling function with field number of 2 and 3 so that function could be performed on those fields.
}
1                                    ##Printing current line here.
' Input_file                         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: It looks today will be 100k, super :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat input
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 1
5 1 0
$ awk '$2 == 0 { $2 = "." } $3 == 0 { $3 = "." }1' input
1 . .
2 . .
3 . .
4 . 1
5 1 .
```

Comment: Thanks William. It solved my problem. I have one question what does 1 refers from your code: $ awk '$2 == 0 { $2 = "." } $3 == 0 { $3 = "." }1' input

Comment: @setegnalemu [What is the meaning of '1' at the end of an awk script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63891/118235)

Answer (score 1):

Using `gnu-awk`:

```sh
awk '{print gensub(/(\s)0(\s)/, "\\1.\\2", "g", gensub(/(\s)0$/, "\\1.", "1"))}' file

1 . .
2 . .
3 . .
4 . 1
5 1 .
```

Comment: it would change `0` to a `.` when it is the first field, but OP wants only 2nd and 3rd fields to change

Comment: I edited on stackoverflow mobile app that puts non-ascii double quotes instead of ascii `"`. Anyway I have 2 solutions and both should work fine.

Comment: you probably didn't get the issue which I'm pointing! consider in first column instead of `1 0\n2 0\n3 1\n4 0\n5 0\n`, it's `0 0\n1 0\n0 2\n4 0\n` , your both commands will replace these 0's in the first column too . `printf '0 0\n1 0\n0 2\n4 0\n' |awk ...`

Comment: Indeed that's the intention since OP stated that zeroes are not there in 1st column.

Comment: I try to resolve all valid comments to the best of my abilities

Answer (score 1):

If there are always 3 fields, you might also loop the last 2 fields and set the value to a dot it any of the values are zero.

```
awk '{                          # Start the program
  for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) {       # Loop only the last 2 fields
    if ($i == 0) $i="."         # If the value of the field is 0, set it to a dot
  }
} 1' file                       # print the whole line
```

Output

```
1 . .
2 . .
3 . .
4 . 1
5 1 .
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use ternary operator (`?:`) for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 1
5 1 0
```

then

```
awk '{$2=$2=="0"?".":$2;$3=$3=="0"?".":$3;print}' file.txt
```

output

```
1 . .
2 . .
3 . .
4 . 1
5 1 .
```

Explanation: ternary operator is more compact alternative to using if-else in this case. It consist of *check*`?`*valueiftrue*`:`*valueifelse*

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will be the shortest `awk`

```
$ awk '!$2{$2="."} !$3{$3="."}1' file

1 . .
2 . .
3 . .
4 . 1
5 1 .
```

still shorter with `sed`

```
$ sed 's/ 0\b/ ./g' file
```